# Cannot set up Android tablet with Family Link

Tags: google-family-link

I bought 2 HUAWEI Mediapad M5 Lite (Android 8) devices for my children, one year apart (both the children ages, and the purchases of the devices). I managed to set up my son's device first with Family Link so that I can control it from my Android 11 phone and other Android devices that I use. However, I cannot get the 2nd one to be "seen" by Family Link. I don't remember exactly how I set them up, doing it one year apart, but I can see that they're both linked to different e-mail addresses that I created for my kids and even the one that cannot be recognized has parental controls enabled (with a warning to "Get more controls" with the Google Family Link app). When I go to the Family Link app and try to add a device for my daughter, I get a message to go to the kid's device ➡ settings ➡ account ➡ parental controls and there I don't see anything else I can do to add the device.

So, other than resetting the device and trying to add the account from scratch, is there anything else I can do?